# In mongodb replication process, I have 3 mongodb instances, should all three instances have to have the data in database?

Tags: mongodb, replication, database-replication

1. All three instances have to have the data in database ?
2. If not, suppose one instance is not responding or hardware failure occurred then how the second instance will get the data ?

Comment: Take a look [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/)

Comment: (1) In a replica-set only the primary node will accept writes. These writes will be replicated to the remaining data-bearing secondary nodes. Not all secondaries need to be data bearing nodes; e.g., a node can be an _Arbiter_. See [Replica-set Architectures](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-architectures/). (2) Only, the data from the primary gets replicated to a secondary. If the primary goes down, an election takes place and one of the available secondaries will become a primary. See [Replica-set elections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-elections/).